# admin.php taking 14 seconds

Tags: performance, debug, optimization

This is a clean install but it has a (relatively) huge database of dummy posts/comments/etc. But even on single-post loads it still takes just as much.

[image: scr]

Narrowing further down `menu.php` takes 8 seconds but I'm lost at where exactly...

[image: scr]

All its sub values are small...

---

**Edit**
Question: Any pointers on where to look for the bottleneck? (that call stack is HUGE, and apparently child-`callable`'s `Time` doesn't add to parent - as seen in `menu.php`)

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere? It's cool you did some benchmarks, but without much direction (eg. "Why does `menu.php` take so long?") there's not much we can do. Also, it looks like you did your bench mark your local server (WAMP, or whatever) which may not be an accurate reflect of the real world.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy Normally it shouldn't take that long, no? Even on a shittiest localserver. I'm not sure how to ask.. where do I go from here?

Comment: There's no near enough information here to tell you how to proceed. What server? How does it perform in a production environment? Server specs? Etc.